# Visitor visa invitation letter original or scanned copy?

Tags: visas, uk, invitation-letters

I'm writing an invitation letter for my friend in Morocco to come and stay with us in England. I was wondering whether anyone knows if the invitation letter needs to be a hand written original sent by post, a printed letter with signatures sent by post, or just a scanned copy of the letter with signatures at the bottom sent by email?

Comment: Scanned copy. My brother used one without any problems. But he, has been staying in US for the past 8 years, not a citizen though. Coming from Morocco, considered a country where people intend to migrate illegally, I would send him the real letter just to be sure.

Answer (score 4):

The invitation letter should be original ([as pointed out in their guidance](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/423699/2015_04_20_Visitor_Supporting_Documents_Guide_-_Final__2__-_CLEAN.pdf)) with 'wet signatures'.

This is especially true if it's the applicant's first visit.  They will (or may) check the font and resolution of the letter.

You didn't mention the contents of the letter, but given the applicant is in Morocco, the letter should be fairly high quality and address all of the concerns they expect from a UK-based host.